# Alpine js - $dispatch from another component -> this.$dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, alpine.js

First sorry for my english!
Im trying to create add to cart ajax button in Shopify with Alpine js and JS Vanilla, but when click in the button the console says this.$dispatch(the dispatchs come from another liquid files) is not a function, i think is something about the scope of the function, im new on alpine and also i didnt find doc about this. I let my code:

```
    <div class="product--information px-4 md:px-0 md:sticky"
                x-data="{
                    addToCart() {
                        let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.product_form);
                        fetch('/cart/add.js', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: formData
                        })
                        .then(response => {
                            return response.json();
                        })
                        .then(response => {
                            this.$dispatch('cart-updated');
                            this.$dispatch('toggle-cart');
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.error('Error:', error);
                        });
                    }
                }"
            >
            {% form 'product', product, id: 'product-form', novalidate: 'novalidate', x-ref: 'product_form' %}
<div class="flex md:w-1/2">
                    <button type="button" @click="addToCart()" class="flex-1 p-4 uppercase bg-black text-white text-center" {% if
                        selected_variant.variant.available==false %} disabled {% endif %}>
                        {% if selected_variant.variant.available == false %}
                        Sold Out
                        {% else %}
                        Add to cart
                        {% endif %}
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs, even without seeing the full code, I could add the following lines of code, but it would be very helpful to add the full code of your "template-product.liquid" file.

Add below product--information this code:

```
{%- assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id -%}
```

like this:

```
<div class="product--information px-4 md:px-0 md:sticky"
{%- assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id -%}
```

and then in the end of code, change:

```
{% form 'product', product, id: 'product-form', novalidate: 'novalidate', x-ref: 'product_form' %}
```

to this:

```
{%- form 'product', product, id: product_form_id, class: 'form', novalidate: 'novalidate', x-ref: 'product_form' -%}
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Gio tenes conocimientos? de shopify? do you have knowlodge about shopify?